# ejabberd: is there a way to determine if a user is an admin?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I've browsed the [module development](http://www.process-one.net/en/wiki/ejabberd_module_development/) documentation but I can't find an API that would help me determine if 'user' (i.e. identified through a JID) is allowed administrative access.

I understand there is the module 'acl' which looks promising (or probably the answer altogether) but no public API is documented.

Should I just assume that the module 'acl' is the proper way to access user credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the acl module is what you're looking for:

```
acl:match_rule(Host, admin, Jid) =:= allow
```

This is true if Jid is an admin for the virtual host Host. (Assuming you have acls that define 'admin' in your ejabberd.cfg file)